# Executing all test cases of webapplication

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, junit4

Ok, so here are my two question related to gmail web application.
So, for example these are test classes, which have got all the test cases related to the functionality:

1) Login

2) Check Inbox

3) Check chat functionality

4) Check Compose mail functionality

5) ....

6) ....
..

..

10) Logout

My first question is :
1) Can i run all the test classes of whole gmail application in one instance ? If its possible then do let me know what framework to be used ? Currently i am using junit4 framework, is it possible by it ?

Second question :
2) Now, here in same gmail application, if i need to run single test class say "Check chat functionality". How to do this ?

Comment: "Can i run all the test classes of whole gmail application in one instance" One instance of what? What code have you tried?

Comment: You sound as though you are testing Gmail's UI for them. Why?

Comment: @Seanny123 : I am learning selenium, so i have created test classes. I need to know how i should create one single instance of the browser, so that i am able to run all the test cases of every class

Comment: @Arran : Well, i can't do UI testing of gmail ? But..let me be clear i am simply learning up selenium and found gmail as proper web application to start with

Comment: Okay, you should edit your question to make that more clear. Also, as for whether you do this in one instance of the web-browser or not, why does it matter? You can do either one. Are you asking which one is more practical or which one is more efficient?

Comment: @Seanny123 : My aim is to complete testing of all the test cases in single browser, multiple browser should not be opened. N i even need to know " is it practical to run all the test cases of application in single browser ? "

Comment: If that's your question, maybe consider rephrasing your original post or asking a new question?

Comment: Of course you can do it, but there are more simpler, more stable and less complex sites to use if you are just testing out Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: Yes, you can do that using JUnit4 framework. In JUnit 4 framwork you will have a annotation "@Test" which represents a test. You can declare all your 1 to 10 test in a Java file marking them as @Test. 
To execute all of them you can use a plugin with eclipse which will all you to execute all at once.

Answer 2: Yes, you can execute tests individually as well. Once you install the JUnit plugin for eclipse you will get a list of tests written in a particular class file.
like...
Test1
Test2
Test3
.. so on.
You just need to select the test you wanna execute and then run it.

Comment: Answer 1: Don't forget that the tests order is important - you have to perform the login before the other tests For that you can use FixMethodOrder annotation (Junit 4.11)

Answer 2: Because of the tests dependency (answer 1) you can use the Category annotations to group several tests


Alternative: Place the login step in a Before (or even better) BeforeClass function

Comment: @lttiel : Thanks for answer :) Can you tel me :- which is better to use  : PageFactory and PageObjects ? or is there any other better option than this.

Comment: I recommend the usage of PageFactory and PageObjects - see details here - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory